# What is the correct visa type to attend a conference in Vietnam?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, vietnam

I have been invited for a talk in a conference by the organizers to be held in Vietnam. I am working as a scientist for the government of India and have an Indian passport. I wish to get a visa for Vietnam. Which type of visa do I need, a tourist visa or a business visa?

Answer (score 1):

Visa to Cambodia, Laos and Thailand is easier to obtain now, you could apply for visa at the arrival airport, while applying for a visa to Vietnam and Myanmar is bit more complicated. Visitors have to apply Visa in advance to enter Myanmar and Vietnam.

You will have 2 options about get a visa to travel to Vietnam:

Option 1: Take your Vietnam Visa Approval Letter and get the visa stamp at the Vietnamese Embassy or Consulate in your home country.

Option 2: Get your visa on arrival at the airport in Vietnam. Visa on arrival is the easiest option, especially if you are pressed for time or have no Vietnamese Embassies in your area. Just bring a copy of your visa approval letter (you may be required to show this when you board the airplane) and a passport size photo.

Answer (score 1):

Vietnam business DN visa is used for working with the Vietnamese Enterprise/ Organization/ Company.
In this case, 1 month single entry business DN visa is good for you.
You can get DN visa approval letter within 3 - 5 working days without providing any special documetation except your passport copy.